# Set default value of Glade Comboboxtext

Tags: application-development, quickly, glade

How can I set a default value of a comboboxtext in Glade? If I run my program with quickly the combobox appears empty until the user choose something from the list. I would like to display the first list entry when the program starts.

Thanks
Stefanie

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Have a look at the following screenshot. You can set the active item in the `General` tab in Glade.

https://i.stack.imgur.com/OfXek.png

If this doesn't work, you can use `Gtk.ComboBoxText.set_active(int)` in your code.